# Retrieving %data from sqlite database java

Tags: java, sqlite

So I have two database table in sqlite: `VendorOrder` and `NewspaperOrder`.

`VendorOrder` db table has (NO,DATE,VENDOR, ...) column (`NO` is like an id#).

```
        DATE             NO   VENDOR   ...
06:57:05 PM 27/07/2017   1    a
09:18:23 AM 28/07/2017   2    b
09:19:08 AM 28/07/2017   3    c
```

`NewspaperOrder` db table has (NO,NEWSPAPER,ORDERS,SUBTOTAL, ...) column.

```
NO   NEWSPAPER   ORDERS    SUBTOTAL  REBATE...
1    bulletin      3          9
1    m times       1          5
1    philstar      2          20
2    bulletin      0          0
2    m times       3          15
2    philstar      0          0
3    bulletin      1          9
3    m times       4          20
3    philstar      5          50
```

I was able to retrieve data for a specific date, using this code.

```
    String sql = "select VendorOrder.VENDOR,NewspaperOrder.NEWSPAPER,NewspaperOrder.ORDERS,NewspaperOrder.SUBTOTAL,NewspaperOrder.REBATE"
            +" from VendorOrder,NewspaperOrder"
            +" where VendorOrder.NO = NewspaperOrder.NO and NewspaperOrder.NEWSPAPER='Bulletin'"
            +" and VendorOrder.DATE like '%"+x+"'  order by VendorOrder.DATE"
            +"";
    pst = sqliteconn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();            
    reportTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    rs.close(); 
    pst.close();
```

Then now, I am trying for specific date range, I was aware that there is syntax for that something like

```
"select * from SummarizedReport where DATA_ID between '"+data1+"' and '"+data2+"' order by DATA_ID"
```

This is the last code I wrote (its not working lol haha)

```
    String sql = "select VendorOrder.VENDOR,NewspaperOrder.NEWSPAPER,NewspaperOrder.ORDERS,NewspaperOrder.SUBTOTAL,NewspaperOrder.REBATE"
            +" from VendorOrder,NewspaperOrder"
            +" where VendorOrder.NO = NewspaperOrder.NO and NewspaperOrder.NEWSPAPER='Bulletin'"
            +" and VendorOrder.DATE between '%"+x+"' and '%"+y+"'  order by VendorOrder.DATE"
            +"";
    pst = sqliteconn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();            
    reportTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    rs.close(); 
    pst.close();
```

Comment: as you are using a prepareStatement put `?` into your SQL and then the paramaters using `setDate` - assuming the field is actually a Date in the DB, if not it should be

Comment: well I already tried using the ? in my sql, its still not working. my variable x and y is already holding the date range values.

Comment: yeah but a date does not have intrinsic formatting - you are making some assumption that how it displays is how it is stored

Comment: What you've shown above is not one of [SQLite's supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). Is that the format of the values in the database, or are you inserting something other than those strings?